# How can I use css for $Session?

Tags: css

If I have the line:

```
$_SESSION["started"] = "ACTIVE SESSION";
```

how can I change the font color using css?

EDIT: It's within PHP code and was wondering how I would change the CSS for it. What identifier would I use?

Comment: That makes no sense at all...

Comment: @ReneKoch Have edited question

Comment: `$_SESSION["started"] = "ACTIVE SESSION";` change to `$_SESSION["started"] = '<span style="color:green">ACTIVE SESSION</span>';`

Answer (score 0):

in html? this is processed on the server side. I dont know what this means actually.

Comment: this is a session variable when you print this within any html tag then you can change the color `<div style="color:red;"><?= $_SESSION['started'];?></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Is this `echo`ed? if it is, `echo` it like this:

```php
<?php
echo <span class="myphpthing">$_SESSION["started"]</span>
?>
```

And then for CSS:

```css
.myphpthing {
  color: red;
}
```

If this wasn't what you were trying to do, give a bit more info, and i can help more.